# Error of inserting data into sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Am working on a project. I want to insert student details into sqlite database but i receive an error in the android monitor that "The TABLE AttendanceList does not have column named surname" and i do have that colunm. i have been stuck for days, please i help.

Here is my code.

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "StudentAttendance";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_AttendanceList = "AttendanceList";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_surname = "surname";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_reg_no = "reg_no";
private static final String KEY_firstname = "firstname";
private static final String KEY_lastname = "lastname";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_AttendanceList_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_AttendanceList + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_reg_no + " TEXT"
            + KEY_firstname + " TEXT"
            + KEY_lastname + "TEXT"
            + KEY_surname +  "TEXT"  + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_AttendanceList_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AttendanceList);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addAttendanceList (AttendanceList AttendanceList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, AttendanceList.getID());
    values.put(KEY_reg_no, AttendanceList.getRegNo()); //  RegNo
    values.put(KEY_firstname, AttendanceList.getFirstname());
    values.put(KEY_lastname, AttendanceList.getLastname()); // lasttname
    values.put(KEY_surname, AttendanceList.getSurname());// surname

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_AttendanceList,null,values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
AttendanceList getAttendanceList(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_AttendanceList, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_reg_no, KEY_firstname, KEY_lastname, KEY_surname }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    AttendanceList AttendanceList = new AttendanceList(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4));
    // return AttendanceList
    return AttendanceList;
}

// Getting All details
public List<AttendanceList> getAllAttendanceList() {
    List<AttendanceList> contactList = new ArrayList<AttendanceList>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_AttendanceList;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            AttendanceList AttendanceList = new AttendanceList();
            AttendanceList.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            AttendanceList.setRegNo(cursor.getString(1));
            AttendanceList.setFirstname(cursor.getString(2));
            AttendanceList.setLastname(cursor.getString(3));
            AttendanceList.setSurname(cursor.getString(4));
            // Adding Attendance to list
            contactList.add(AttendanceList);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return Attendancelist
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single Attendance List
public int updateContact(AttendanceList AttendanceList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_reg_no, AttendanceList.getRegNo());
    values.put(KEY_firstname, AttendanceList.getFirstname());
    values.put(KEY_lastname, AttendanceList.getLastname());
    values.put(KEY_surname, AttendanceList.getSurname());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_AttendanceList, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(AttendanceList.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single List item
public void deleteListItem(AttendanceList AttendanceList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_AttendanceList, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(AttendanceList.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting List Count
public int getListCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_AttendanceList;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

}

StudentTake100Activity.java

```
public class StudentTake100Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView lvStudentlist;
private StudentListAdapter adapter;
private List<StudentList> mStudentList;
private CheckBox checkBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_take100);

    lvStudentlist= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_studentlist);


    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    mStudentList = new ArrayList<>();
    //Add sample data for list
    //We can get data from DB, webservice here
    mStudentList.add(new StudentList(1, "U11EE1001", "Bargo","S.","Mayafi"));
    mStudentList.add(new StudentList(2, "U11EE1002", "Barnsbas","Snake.","Maciji"));
    mStudentList.add(new StudentList(3, "U11EE1004", "Adamu","Tanko.","Sadau"));
    mStudentList.add(new StudentList(4, "U11EE1005", "Munzali","","Cire Tallafi"));


    //Init adapter
    adapter = new StudentListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mStudentList);
    lvStudentlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    lvStudentlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            StudentList studentList = (StudentList)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            String reg_no = studentList.getReg_no();
            String firstname = studentList.getFirstname();
            String lastname = studentList.getLasttname();
            String surname = studentList.getSurname();

            db.addAttendanceList(new AttendanceList(reg_no,firstname,lastname,surname));


        }
    });

}
```

}

AttendaneList.java

```
public class AttendanceList {
//private variables
int _id;
String _reg_no;
String _firstname;
String _lastname;
String _surname;

// Empty constructor
public AttendanceList(){

}
// constructor
public AttendanceList(int id, String _reg_no, String _firstname, String _lastname, String _surname){
    this._id = id;
    this._reg_no = _reg_no;
    this._firstname = _firstname;
    this._lastname = _lastname;
    this._surname = _surname;
}

// constructor
public AttendanceList(String _reg_no, String _firstname, String _lastname, String _surname){
    this._reg_no = _reg_no;
    this._firstname = _firstname;
    this._lastname = _lastname;
    this._surname = _surname;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting regNo
public String getRegNo(){
    return this._reg_no;
}

// setting regNo
public void setRegNo(String reg_no){
    this._reg_no = reg_no;
}

// getting firstname
public String getFirstname(){
    return this._firstname;
}

// setting firstname
public void setFirstname(String firstname){
    this._firstname = firstname;
}

// getting lastname
public String getLastname(){
    return this._lastname;
}

// setting lastname
public void setLastname(String lastname){
    this._lastname = lastname;
}
// getting surname
public String getSurname(){
    return this._surname;
}

// setting surname
public void setSurname(String surname){
    this._surname = surname;
}
```

}

[logcat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVYGY.png)

[syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWbWD.png)

```
06-22 10:58:04.576 2936-2961/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xeeab85e0
06-22 10:58:05.957 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ")": syntax error
06-22 10:58:05.959 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
06-22 10:58:05.959 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE AttendanceList(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,reg_no TEXT,firstname TEXT,lastname TEXT,surname TEXT,)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance.DatabaseHandler.onCreate(DatabaseHandler.java:47)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance.DatabaseHandler.addAttendanceList(DatabaseHandler.java:66)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance.StudentTake100Activity$1.onItemClick(StudentTake100Activity.java:54)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3891)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3656)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9294)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2547)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
06-22 10:58:05.961 2936-2936/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/MessageQueue-JNI:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputS
```

ViewAttendanceActivity

```
public class ViewAttendanceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView lvStudentlist;
private StudentListAdapter adapter;
private List<StudentList> mStudentList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_attendance);

    lvStudentlist= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_studentlist);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    SQLiteDatabase connection;
    connection = db.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor result=connection.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM AttendanceList", null);//  database query for all AttendanceList in your table
    while(result.moveToNext ())
        mStudentList.add(new StudentList(result.getInt(0),result.getString(1),result.getString(2),result.getString(3),result.getString(4)));

    mStudentList = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new StudentListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mStudentList);
    lvStudentlist.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

Error

06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance, PID: 1650
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance.ViewAttendanceActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance.ViewAttendanceActivity.onCreate(ViewAttendanceActivity.java:31)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
06-24 17:41:05.354 1650-1650/com.sunusi2sim.mobileattendance E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

Comment: Where's the logcat? Please post it.

Comment: this is why we should not allow people to write sql.

Comment: Do you have added this column "surname" later in application ? 


If yes then just do one thing completely uninstall application from device and then install and run again

Comment: No. Am building the app and test run using emulator. Am so tired of this error.

Answer (score 2):

Your create table query is messing it up. Column name and its type should have a space in between and also comma is missing. Use this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_AttendanceList_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_AttendanceList + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_reg_no + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_firstname + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_lastname + " TEXT," 
        + KEY_surname +  " TEXT"  + ")"; 
    db.execSQL(CREATE_AttendanceList_TABLE);
}
```

You will have to uninstall the app first then run the updated code.

Comment: Thanks...I have done that, clear and rebuild the project but am still having thesame error in the logcat.

Comment: Did you install the old app from your device? You need to install the old app to make it work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I now got more errors(syntax error), but am happy i will not see "The TABLE AttendanceList does not have column named surname" again.

Comment: No, in my code. See my syntax error image if u can help out.

Comment: Can you copy paste that error? I can't see the full error.

Comment: it look messy..Hope it can helps.

Comment: You have added extra comma at the end of query. Check my code.

Comment: I have correct that and got another error... I have paste the log if you want to help out.

Comment: You are trying to add a row with id=1 but another one with same id exist. `id` is the primary key so you can't add another row with id = 1. Make id auto increment too and while inserting don't pass id.

Comment: Wow..Awesome. You are great, i will like to be like you when i grow up. Please help me with this last activity. I want to display my inserted data in my custom listview but am getting an  error. Please check my ViewAttendance an error.